# What happens to electricity when it goes into the ground?

Tags: electricity

Every electrical pole on the planet, and many (all?) residential electrical networks are connected to the Earth. Also, every building has a lightning rod that's meant to route lightning strikes into the ground.
It is my understanding that nothing in the Universe can just disappear, energy simply changes location or state.

What exactly happens to the electrons that get routed to the ground when they get there? Do they accumulate in it, or are they dissipated and if yes, how?

Comment: A wire that is stretched for miles on poles above the ground and electrically insulated from the ground effectively becomes one "plate" of a capacitor. The Earth itself is the other plate, and atmospheric electricity can charge that capacitor to dangerous voltages. The purpose of a ground wire on each pole is to _discharge_ that capacitor.  Learn more about [what capacitors are](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capacitor) and how they work, and you will have a better understanding of why the power grid is grounded.

Comment: Power grids are grounded in order to prevent voltages on the grid from attaining those of lightning strikes, which would literally wipe out the grid. By grounding the grid a low impedance path is provided for discharging the currents involved.

Comment: P.S., Thunder clouds act like [static electricity generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_generator), causing a huge potential difference (i.e., Voltage) between the top of the cloud and the base of the cloud.  Cloud-to-ground lightning strikes happen because the base of the cloud is relatively close to the Earth, and it charges the Earth by _[induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_induction)_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What exactly happens to the electrons that get routed to the ground
>   when they get there? Do they accumulate in it, or are they dissipated
>   and if yes, how?

The earth, being so large, can easily accept or supply excess charge. While lightning is constantly charging the Earth, the Earth is constantly discharging to the atmosphere so that the Earth remains electrically neutral.

The majority of the energy of the lightning discharge is dissipated in the air as it travels from the clouds to the ground through the air. The remainder is dissipated in the ground in the area surrounding the location of the strike, over a fairly short distance.

Hope this helps.